# What does an asterisk (*) after a variable name mean in opengl?

Tags: function, class, pointers, opengl

I'm seeing this line in a source that I'm studying but can't seem to find anything related to "asterisk after variable" or "variable before asterisk". What does it mean?

```
GameDrawer* gameDrawer;
```

GameDrawer is also used as a name for a function and class.

Comment: This isn't OpenGL specific; it's basic C/C++ syntax.  How are you using C++, to the point of messing with OpenGL, without having seen a pointer before?

Comment: I've just been skimming through C++ tutorials. I've seen how pointers are declared , but only as being declared as a type. int, char, "int * GameDrawer;" etc etc. first time coming across a "pointer to a class" making that class a valid "type".

Comment: Since GLSL does not support pointers or operator overloading, if you see this in OpenGL it means multiply `GameDrawer` by `gameDrawer`. I have to imagine instead, that this is some form of C code and has nothing to do with OpenGL or its C-like language (GLSL).

Comment: @CodeSeven: In C++, classes *are* types.  Once defined as a class, `GameDrawer` is nearly equivalent to `int`; you can have variables of that type, have pointers and references to instances of it, use it as a type parameter in templates, etc etc etc. About all you can't do is (1) use it as the underlying type of an enum, and (2) `memcpy` its instances around willy-nilly.  (You can actually even do (2) in some cases, with so-called "trivially copyable" types.  But til you understand what "trivially copyable" means, it's safer to assume you can't.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be the c++ notation for a pointer.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#pointers_to_classes

Answer (score 4):

Here, `*` is called **dereference operator**. This defines a pointer; a variable which stores the address of another variable is called a pointer. Pointers are said to **point to** the variable whose address they store.

Check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

```
Correct me if I’m wrong, but I think all of these are the same thing:
• GameDrawer * gameDrawer;
• GameDrawer* gameDrawer;
• GameDrawer *gameDrawer;
```

The syntax doesn’t care where the spaces are, as long as there is one. These statements are declaring a pointer by the name of gameDrawer which is of type GameDrawer. Assuming GameDrawer is a class.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, asterisk is used to indicate variable 'gameDrawer' is of type **pointer to GameDrawer**. And it's also used to deference a pointer to get the variable the pointer is bound.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more commnet, I encountered this post when I saw a code that has a asterisk after a variable instead of class or struct. And in this case, I finally realize that the asterisk here is a multiplication operator.